# Car vs Tricycle getting rear ended

Tags: friction, collision

Suppose you have a car sitting stationary. Then it gets rear ended by a truck going at $x$ speed.

Then you have a tricycle with the same size wheels and same weight. It also gets hit by a truck also going at $x$ speed.

Assume the roads on which the car and the tricycle have the same amount of friction. Also assume the collision transfers the same amount of force.
Also assume there is no drag.
Also assume the collision is perfectly elastic.

My question is: **Would the tricycle go farther than the car?**

**My reasoning:** there are only three wheels on the tricycle, so there is one less point of friction on the tricycle and therefore it takes longer to stop because there is less friction.

But my fellow student says the car and the tricycle would go the same distance because the car and the tricycle weigh the same, so the friction on each of the wheels of the tricycle is actually more than the friction on each of the wheels of the car.

**Which of us is correct and why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'll go the same distance. The number of points of contacts doesn't matter, since as you reduce the number of contact points, they each support more weight and can therefore apply more friction.

The force applied by kinetic friction is $\mu N$, which on flat stationary ground is just $\mu mg$. With a tricycle, you'll have $3$ wheels each applying a force of $1/3 \mu mg$, and with a regular car you'll have $4$ wheels each applying a force of $1/4 \mu mg$ - the total either way is $\mu mg$.

Note that you can put two wheels of the car right next to each other and effectively have a "three-wheeled" vehicle, but there is no reason why simply thinking about the wheels differently should change the stopping distance.